# What strategy should I use to copy a git branch from one repo into a branch of another repo?

Tags: git

I have a git branch that I need to copy from one repository to a branch within another repository.

From:
Repo_A
Branch: develop

Top:
Repo_B
Branch: Whatever

I cannot simply mirror Repo_A into Repo_B as Repo_B has restrictions on commits, so everything must go into a branch, approved by others, and the merged into the master branch.

What is the best way to go about doing this?  Should I simply clone Repo_A, checkout branch 'develop', then create a branch on Repo_B and simply copy the contents of 'develop' into the new branch and push the changes?  Or is there a better strategy?

Comment: Can the two repos be accessed at the same time? Are they on the same machine?

Comment: I can only clone/push/etc; I do not have any other access to the machine.  But yes, they are on the same machine.

Comment: just clone and then push to another repo

Answer (score 0):

You add a other remote can call it Repo_A on your local git, pull from the Repo_A into a new branch can call branch_repo_a,

Make another new branch from the branch you want to merge let's say in Repo_B you have the branch dev so i checkout a new branch from Repo_B/dev i we can call it dev_A_B (do the new branch from Repo_B in case somenthing goes wrong with the merge)

then do the merge in dev_A_B 
  git merge branch_repo_a

And there you have all the code merge, well you did not ask for the merge suggestion, but :)

Answer (score 0):

```
git clone Repo_A
git push Repo_B develop:Whatever
```

Where Repo_A and Repo_B are names of remotes.